# Computer Upgrade

Tags: windows-vista, upgrade, hardware-rec, computer-building

I have a problem: when I am playing games, my computer freezes and displays a blue screen.  I suspect it has something to do with the hard drive which was repaired by Seagate Technicians via warranty just 2 months back.  Otherwise, it's been running smoothly, although lately, sometimes during data transfer the computer ceases to do any other tasks.

I am using Windows Vista 64-bit OEM trial version.  My current specs:

```
Motherboard:    ASUS M3A
Processor:      AMD Phenom X4 9550
RAM:            Dynet 2 GB DDR2 
Graphics Card:  NVIDIA 8600 GT
Hard Drives:    Seagate Barracuda 500 GB (SATA)
                Seagate 40 GB (PATA)
```

Should upgrade to a 1 TB HDD or just keep the 500 GB HDD + 2 GB ram for the sole purpose of gaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freezing and "blue screening" are more a sign of bad memory than of a bad hard drive. I would recommend swapping out the memory modules one by one and see if the freezing still happens.

Concerning your other question (upgrade): I would definitely add more ram, especially when running a 64bit OS (actually, with less than 4 GB of ram I think you better stick with 32bit). The hard drive size is not that important, especially when you already have 500GB. There's no game yet (at least that I know of) that needs that much free hard drive space ;-)

Comment: HDD Size is never enough! I got 2terrabytes on my home computer and around 40gb free space! :)

Comment: @Jonas: You should not keep everything on your internal hard drive. If you have that much data, I recommend a NAS or at least some external usb drives.